# Excel Line chart is NOT continuous

Tags: excel, charts, excel-formula

Following is the range and its associated chart. The problem is, that line chart is NOT **continuous** even though I have replaced zero values with `=NA()`. It means dates 2019/02 and 2019/09 should NOT be shown.

[image: data range]
[image: chart]

Comment: have you removed those dates from the x-axis? since they are there excel plots them.

Comment: I just want those dates to be removed automatically.

Comment: Excel will plot those dates as part of the x-axis you specify. Just plotted your data without those dates and it plots but you then have an, in my opinion, incorrect x-axis as the spacing changes which can lead people to erroneous conclusions. Another solution is to overlay one chart on top with the second series but don't include the missing value...

Comment: A quick fix would be to filter the data as you've posted - `=FILTER(A1:B8,ISNUMBER(A1:A8))`.and base your chart off that with a text x-axis.  Would be better to remove them with your initial formula though and as @SolarMike said people might miss that change in spacing.

Comment: Unsolicited tip. If you get in the habit of putting the X values (dates) to the left of the Y values, you will find it easier to selecting the data and clicking a button on the Insert tab, without having to use the Select Data dialog to fix the data.